# How to change file permissions using os.chmod while preserving existing permissions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-permissions, chmod, stat

I'm trying to selectively modify permissions for user, group, or others all at once, but whenever I use `chmod`, all permissions are overwritten.

---

I've tried oring together current file permissions with the new permission as suggested in `chmod` documentation:

ex:

```
GROUP_RO = S_IRGRP #Group read only
current_permissions = stat.S_IMODE(os.stat(path).st_mode)

os.chmod(path, current_permissions | GROUP_RO)
```

I've also tried using bit masks. I couldn't figure out a way to combine the bit masks to where - if I'm modifying user permissions, I can protect/mask both group and others permissions from being modified.

I've tried using bit masks in the following way:

```
GROUP_RO = S_IRGRP #Group read only
USER_MASK = S_IRWXU

os.chmod(path, USER_MASK | GROUP_RO) #this works at preventing User permissions from being modified
```

But piping multiple masks together does not:

```
USER_MASK = S_IRWXU
OTHERS_MASK = S_IRWXO

os.chmod(path, USER_MASK | OTHERS_MASK | GROUP_RO) #does not work
```

I've tried endless combinations of different bitwise operators, and bit masks, with or without current permissions and no luck.

---

What I would like to be able to do:

```
# current permissions -> U: read only, G: read and write, O: write only
os.chmod(path, [whatever code making this work])
# new permissions -> U: read only, G: read only, O: write only
```

In any situation, other entities are not modified.

Comment: The example you show has invalid syntax. Could you show a working example and what you tried with but masks?

Comment: @MadPhysicist twas a typo. I fixed it and added examples of other solutions I've attempted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your attempts come quite close. The problem is that the `|` operator can't turn off bits. So when you do `current_permissions | S_IRGRP`, you're setting the right bits, but you're not turning off the write permission.

To turn off bits, you need `&`. There are a few good ways to do this.

The one I'd choose is probably to unset all group permissions, and set them to what you want:

```
(current_permissions & ~S_IRWXG) | S_IRGRP
```

The first part unsets all group permissions, and the second part applies read only mode as before.

Another way would be to disable everything but user and other sections, then set the group:

```
(current_permissions & (S_IRWXU | S_IRWXO)) | S_IRGRP
```

The two are generally equivalent, unless you have some weird bits set in your permissions.

Comment: Is this essentially a formula I can use to independently modify permissions of user, group, or others? -> os.chmod( (CURRENT_PERMS & ~MASK_OF_ENTITY_TO_BE_MOTIFIED) | NEW_PERMS_OF_ENTITY_TO_BE_MOTIFIED). I have to read up more on your answer and os.stat to see exactly what you mean and what's going on with the bits.

Comment: @Dante. Yes, you got the general idea. The solution is general like you say. Understand what bitwise negation `~`, bitwise and `&` and bitwise or `|` do and it will become quite clear.

Comment: I answered my own comment - I just tested it - this is fantastic. Thank you, I appreciate your explanation as well, this help me greatly besides with chmod.